# Computed vs Observes on Controller in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

It was always my understanding that `.observes('someProperty')` and `.property('someProperty')` worked exactly the same, except that the former is used for triggering function calls and the latter is used to keep object properties up to date.

But now I'm having a problem. My controller code looks like this:

```
_logChange: function(){
    console.log('model array observer fired');
}.observes('model.@each'),

statsData: function(){
    console.log('statsData being updated');
    ...
    return someArray;
}.property('model.@each')
```

**The observer and computed property both watch model.@each but for some reason, the observer fires on every model change and the property only updates TWICE before mysteriously going dead.** `statsData` is calculated once on initial page load, and once on the first route transition, then after that, none of the transitions (with the changes in the underlying `model` they make) affect it.

What's going on here? Shouldn't they respond to change in the same way?

Note that I *am* using the `statsData` property in my template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the lovely folks on Ember IRC, I was able to figure it out. The problem was that I was passing `statsData` to a component, like this: `{{common-statistics values=statsData}}` and in the component, I had this function:

```
_validateValues: function(){
    var values = this.get('values');
    if(!values || !Ember.isArray(values) || values.length === 0)
    {
        this.set('values',[]);
    }
}.on('willInsertElement')
```

which is, as you can see, setting `values` if it's not what the component is expecting. Unfortunately, this was affecting `statsData` on the controller as well, thanks to [this JavaScript language feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3638034/2069194). By setting `statsData` in the component, I was breaking the computed property on the controller.

So it was never a problem with Ember at all. I just failed to realize that object properties on Ember objects behave the same way they do on "regular JavaScript objects."

Comment: I wanted to add that I had no setter logic defined in the computed property for `values`, and THAT'S why the computed property was breaking; it was being completely overridden with a vanilla JS array. Gotta remember, setter logic in computed properties!

Answer (score 2):

observers fire immediately, computed's fire as part of the run loop and scheduled in a debounced fashion.  Currently all you're watching is that you add or remove an item to the collection, not whether or not a property on one of the items in the collection has changed.  If you want to watch a particular property, you need to specify it.

```
statsData: function(){
    console.log('statsData being updated');
    ...
    return someArray;
}.property('model.@each.cost')
```

if you just want to watch the collection changing you should just use `[]`

```
statsData: function(){
    console.log('statsData being updated');
    ...
    return someArray;
}.property('model.[]')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I didn't know that about observers firing immediately vs computed's firing in the run loop. I also didn't know the real difference between @each and []. Good information! I actually figured out my problem, though, and it turned out not to be an Ember problem at all. I posted an answer.